# How to generate barcode 128 for os x, objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, barcode

I'm working on a project for a OSX and I'm using xcode 4.6.3. I need to generate a barcode image with Encoding 128, and insert it in a pdf file.
I've been researching and I can't figure out how I can do that. I tried to use [cocoabarcode](http://code.google.com/p/cocoabarcodes/), I solved ARC error, but stil have some error tried to replace

```
sAttr = [[NSMutableAttributedString allocWithZone:[self zone]] initWithString:leftCaption attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,leftAligmentStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kerning],NSKernAttributeName,nil]];
```

(error: zone is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode),
and other warnings deprecated methods,

I want to know if someone it's ussing this library, if it's work propertly, or if there are other library like [this](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/) one for iphone, but I need for OSX, or any other suggestion about what classes or library I should research.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, any library recommend?

Comment: What is a barcode 128?

Comment: @Prof. Falken , Its a type of encoding, [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128)

Comment: ok, sorry for my  short explanation of the problem, I will try to rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

May spire.barcode could help you, it supports [Code 128 Barcode](https://freebarcode.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you @Ring, and are there any in objective-c? I've been looking also zxing, zbar, cocoanetics, onbarcode, but I don't know how to implement in my project, and for osx I didn't found